# Associate image is not zooming in thumbnail list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Thanks in advance. Please help me to figure out my problem.
I have a thumbnail list in which, when particular image is selected it comes in as the main image. When main image is hovered the zoom should work.Zoom actually works perfectly.My problem is the image which zooms is not the corresponding image that i've selected.It always zooms only the image i have set as default.please do help me to come up with a solution.

**Html code**

```
<span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
<div  class="prdmainimg"><img id="imgDisp"   src="loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[0];?>" height="495" width="310"/></div>
            </span>
<div class="prdsubcnt" >
<div  class="prdsubcl1"><img  src="loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[1]; ?>" width="65" height="100" onClick="changeImage('loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[1]; ?>')"    /></div> 
<div class="prdsubcl1"><img src="loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[2]; ?>" width="65" height="100" 
onClick="changeImage('loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[2]; ?>'); "/> </div>
<div class="prdsubcl1"><img src="loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[3]; ?>" width="65" height="100" 
onClick="changeImage('loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[3]; ?>')" /></div>
<div class="prdsubcl1"><img src="loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" width="65" height="100" 
onClick="changeImage('loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[0]; ?>'); "/> </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**java script**

```
function changeImage(imgName)
{
  image = document.getElementById('imgDisp');
  image.src = imgName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of onclick function u can use the below code to perform ur task..

```
$('.prdsubcl1 img').on('click',function(){
var src = $(this).attr('src');
$('#imgDisp').attr('src', src);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/iKOSuME/4/edit)

[PureJs](http://jsbin.com/iKOSuME/5/edit) enjoy

```
$('#imgDisp').click(function() {$('#ex1').zoom(); }); this the ur zoom code isn't it use the same code should zoom...i could'nt able to add in fiddle but should work..
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.Actually my problem is with this code given below.The problem arises only when the zoom function is working.The clicked image src is loaded in the (imDisp) but appropriate image is not loading for the zoom function.                                                                                              <div  class="prdmainimg"><img id="imgDisp"   src="loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[0];?>" height="495" width="310"/></div>

Comment: i am sry can u afford to use jquery in ur task as in my code nothing is gonna change but the traditional onclick of js...

Comment: For ur refference i have also added pure js code in fiddle check out..http://jsbin.com/iKOSuME/5/edit

Comment: thank you. your code is perfectly working.but my issue is with the zoom.(class='zoom' id='ex1') This just like a cloud zoom function,This function only works for the src which is loaded at the time of page loading.When thumbnail image are changed the main image is also changed.But problem arises only when that main image is zoomed,at the time of zooming it shows the image which is present in the src="loom-admin/image/products/<?php echo $image[0];?>".Is there any other means in getting the solution?

Comment: I have got the code from this site. You can download the hover zoom from it. http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/  .I couldn't paste the entire code here. Please help in this because am a beginner in JQuery & Js.

Comment: when u change the image src u should pass src as  paramenter to zoom function and apply it to url..will do

Comment: Thank You so much.This is the original function they have written $(document).ready(function(){
$('#ex1').zoom(src);
});                                                                    Given below is the code i have written                                 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#imgDisp').click(function() { 
var src = $('#imgDisp').attr('src');
alert(src);
$('#ex1').zoom(src);
});
});                                                                 Now the zoom itself is not working.Can you help me to code it, it will be so helpful for me.

Comment: sry now i check the js from link u no need to add  src from  $('#ex1').zoom(src); this line $('#ex1').zoom(); when u click just zoom the div u have already used should work..

Comment: Thank You so much man. I have made it correct with your guidance.Really i was helpful with your effort.This is what i have changed in the code  $('.prdsubcl1 img').on('click',function(){
var src = $(this).attr('src');
$('#imgDisp').attr('src', src);
$('#ex1').zoom(src);
});